# Multiple tabs in Windows and gvim

Tags: windows, vim, tabs

I am trying to get the `Edit with Vim` context menu to open files in a new tab of the previously opened Gvim instance (if any).

Currently, using `Regedit` I have modified this key:

```
\HKEY-LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vim\Gvim\path = "C:\Programs\Vim\vim72\gvim.exe" -p --remote-tab-silent "%*"
```

The registry key type is `REG_SZ`.

This almost works... Currently it opens the file in a new tab, but it also opens another tab (which is the active tab) the tab is labeled `\W\S\--literal` and the file seems to be trying to open the following file.

```
C:\Windows\System32\--literal
```

I think the problem is around the `"%*"` - I tried changing that to `"%1"` but if i do that I get an extra tab called `%1`.

**Affected version**

- Vim version 7.2 (same behaviour on 7.1)
- Windows vista home premium

Thanks for any help.

David.

Comment: I withdrew my answer because I can see that I misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting it to: "C:\Programs\Vim \vim72\gvim.exe" -p --remote-tab-silent "%1" "%*"

See: http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=1314

EDIT: As pointed out by Thomas, vim.org tips moved to: http://vim.wikia.com/

See: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_open-in-tabs_context_menu_for_Windows

Comment: This old vim.org tips have moved. kobusb: could you edit your answer to mention this instead? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_open-in-tabs_context_menu_for_Windows

Comment: You might as well also add the search: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?searchx=Search&search=context+menu&go=Try+exact because the whole open-in-tabs-with-context-menu set of tips has gotten messy over at the vim tips wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer... The link to cream gave me some additional areas to search around.

from http://genotrance.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/my-vim-customization/ there is a vim.reg registry file that contains the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Vim]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Vim\command]
@="\"C:\\Programs\\vim\\vim72\\gvim.exe\" -p --remote-tab-silent \"%1\" \"%*\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\gvim.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Programs\\vim\\vim72\\gvim.exe\" -p --remote-tab-silent \"%1\" \"%*\""
```

this gives me the behaviour I want.

So I guess my original plan of editing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE was just wrong.

Would also be nice to know what exactly what the "%1" and "%*" mean/ refer to.

Now... should I edit my original question, to show that I was starting off in the wrong registry area?

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track:

```
HKEY-LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vim\Gvim\path = "C:\Programs\Vim \vim72\gvim.exe" -p
```

was sufficient ... it works!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Cream is a set of scripts and add-ons that sit on top of gVim. Cream doesn't change the appearance of gVim, but it does change the way it behaves.

One of those behaviours is a tabbed document interface. Other behaviours are listed [here](http://cream.sourceforge.net/featurelist.html). The downloads page is [here](http://cream.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an even cleaner fix using your `_vimrc`. Add the following line:
`autocmd BufReadPost * tab ball`
from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1720